# Is It Possible To Execute A .dex that is obtained when installing an apk?

Tags: android

I asked this question to help solve my doubt, and my question is this: Is it possible to run the .dex you get when installing an apk? I have my doubts because I want to be able to move and execute an application that is installed from my application. I explain: I may be able to move with all the files of this one like the apk, the dex, the Cahe. Among others, and be able to run that application. And according to my research, an application runs from your .dex file. True? If not, please correct. Thank you very much.

Comment: "I want to be able to an application" did you miss the verb?

Comment: I have corrected it, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Simple answer:

Android only allows you to start an app via Intents. An intent will only start the app if it is installed. Android decides where the app is installed and will start it from there. A third-party app cannot move an app and instruct the OS to start it from there.

### Detailed:

While there are (rather complex) [ways](https://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/DexClassLoader.html) to run code from dex files directly (without having Android install them), it does not work the same way as starting the app would: The code from the dex won't get its own process, interaction with the OS doesn't work the same,...

Comment: But as does link2SD that moves the application to the SD card. Thank you

Comment: Well, it seems like you are actually asking something different than your question title implies; My answer refers to the question title. link2SD uses file system links to trick the system into thinking it runs the apps from the usual app location. It still requires installation. You'll notice link2sd requires root.

Comment: Thank you for your response and correction. I'm going to create another question about the process that takes Link2SD